# how to use namespace in PHP

Tags: php, oop

I am working on a package that would have different classes. Say Package Name is `Languages` and classes would be like `English`, `French` etc.

Now if I declare a class like

```
namespace Language;
class English
{}
```

How will namespace help to package entire thing and let user of class to call Package Name anyway in his  caller file?

Comment: I have but I am not finding way to get some decent example of it. I am quite clear what I am asking about.

Comment: There's no alternative like java where you can `import Language` and class English directly. You will need to import every single class of this namespace, if you are going to use it. Otherwise, you would need to write the namespace as well, while using the class. `use Language\English` then `$lang = new English()` or, `$lang = new Language\English()` without `use`

Comment: You need to set up an autoloader that deals with the full class name (including the namespace) and maps it to a valid PHP file containing the class you are trying to use.

Comment: True power of PHP namespacing comes when sticking to (quasi) standards. http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/ and https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP you you can either include the namespace with the class name when instantiating the an object:

```
$language = new \Language\English();
```

or you can [import](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php) the class using the "use" keyword:

```
use \Language\English;
$language = new English();
```

All of this is fairly well documented [here](https://www.php.net/namespaces).

Comment: This doesn't cover the fact that you still need to include the relevant PHP files before you can `use` anything inside of them.

Comment: @Marty I know that typical `include` still requires. The reason I want to use namespace to avoid conflicts due to same name of classes. If that could be achieved then enough for me.

Comment: @Volatil3 if you want to avoid name conflicts you can always specify a custom name where needed `use \Language\English as Engrish`

Answer (score 0):

Namespaces provide a level of direction to specific identifiers, thus making it possible to distinguish between identifiers with the same exact name.

simple example given on `[PHP Manual][1]`

As a concrete example, the file `foo.txt` can exist in both directory `/home/greg` and in `/home/other`, but two copies of `foo.txt` cannot co-exist in the same directory. In addition, to access the `foo.txt` file outside of the `/home/gre`g directory, we must prepend the directory name to the file name using the directory separator to get `/home/greg/foo.txt`.

one can then access that class by `Language/English` in the caller file for your code.this will differentiate it from any other class `English`.

Answer (score 0):

Namespaces help separate your code logically, and in separate files and folders.

The client of your `English` and `French` classes might look like this:

```
<?php

use Language\English;
use Language\French;

class Speaking
{
    public function greetInEnglish()
    {
        $english = new English();
        $english->sayHello();
    }

    public function greetInFrench()
    {
        $french = new French();
        $french->sayHello();
    }
}
```

For packaging your code, you should use a package manager. The best php package manager is composer http://getcomposer.org

Most composer packages utilize namespaces, and an autoloader, look at the source of some packages on github to get the idea of it. Writing composer packages is a great way to modularize your code and distribute it.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

we will define a constant, function with the namespace:

```
namespace Language;
class English
{
  public function Testclass(){
    return __METHOD__;
  }
}

$lang = __NAMESPACE__.'\\Testclass'
$obj = new $lang;
echo $obj->Testclass();
```